Problem with GCC trying to converto .o file to .exe
I'm trying to convert a .o file to .exe and this error appears and the code is just a simple hello world code. I'm with MinGW installed and git bash, i tried on it and the same error appears, i'm breaking my head with this.
I'm using make file to generate the .o file (output) and i think thats it
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("Hello world!");
    return 0;
}

compiled with gcc src/main.c -o pluto.o
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\program\Pluto> gcc -v -o a.exe pluto.o

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'a.exe' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/collect2.exe -plugin c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/liblto_plugin-0.dll -plugin-opt=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaeozEq.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -Bdynamic -o a.exe c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0 -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../.. pluto.o -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtend.o
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x2a0): multiple definition of `_mingw32_init_mainargs'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x2a0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.       
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x2e0): multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x2e0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.       
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x300): multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x300): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x320): multiple definition of `atexit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x320): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.       
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x330): multiple definition of `_onexit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x330): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.       
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x340): multiple definition of `__gcc_register_frame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.       
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x430): multiple definition of `__gcc_deregister_frame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0xf0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `_argc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.       
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `_argv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.       
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.eh_frame+0xb8): multiple definition of `__EH_FRAME_BEGIN__'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.eh_frame+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `_Jv_RegisterClasses'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\program\Pluto> gcc src/main.c -c pluto.o
gcc.exe: warning: pluto.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\program\Pluto> gcc src/main.c -o pluto.o
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\program\Pluto> gcc -o a.exe pluto.o     
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x2a0): multiple definition of `_mingw32_init_mainargs'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x2a0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.       
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x2e0): multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x2e0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x300): multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x300): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.       
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x320): multiple definition of `atexit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x320): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.       
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x330): multiple definition of `_onexit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x330): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x340): multiple definition of `__gcc_register_frame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.       
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x430): multiple definition of `__gcc_deregister_frame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0xf0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.       
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `_argc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.       
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `_argv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.       
pluto.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.eh_frame+0xb8): multiple definition of `__EH_FRAME_BEGIN__'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.eh_frame+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `_Jv_RegisterClasses'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

the error persists without the flag -v
I tried to search something about it and found nothing

Welcome! You say "the code is just a simple hello world code". Please add the complete code to the post using the Edit button.

Please show the source of this pluto.o file and how you build it. Also remove this -v switch, it only clutters the useful output.

the error persists with and without -v flag, and i updated the post

compiled with gcc src/main.c -o pluto.o - So you can "convert" it by simply renaming :) You did not build object, you have built an executable. If you wanted to build an object, you should have used gcc src/main.c  -c -o pluto.o

Upvoted for including the code, the build command, and the logs. Though the question should be closed or deleted.
